# How to strip 1 and/or 2 words from field

Tags: python

Novice in python. Trying to display a label in `ArcGIS` map using python. Have tried several expressions but can't seem to strip the words 'Branch' and/or 'Library' from my field called `SITE_NAME`. Some values for SITE_NAME are stored as

```
"[name of city] Branch Library"
```

and others are

```
"[name of city] Library"
```

I don't want my labels to show either of these on the map because it looks too busy. Some of the city names contain the string `"Ranch"` so those were also getting stripped - for example if the name is `"Weston Ranch Branch Library"` I only want the label to be `"Weston Ranch"` or if the name was `"Weston Library"` only display `"Weston."` Thanks.

```py
def FindLabel ( [SITE], [SITE_NAME] ):
    return [SITE]+"-"+[SITE_NAME]
```

Comment: `label = label.replace('Branch Library', '').replace('Library', '')` seems like a reasonable start, but it's tough to tell much about the form of your data

Comment: Perhaps give us an example?

Comment: Thank you! Told you I was a novice. Didn't know I could use 2 replace commands.

Comment: How do I mark as answered?  FAQ says to check the right answer. How do I do that?

Comment: @user11886696 I entered it as a comment because I wasn't clear on your question, but shash678 has entered the same approach with a more flexible way to remove undesired strings, so you can accept that by clicking the check mark on its side.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two replace statements followed by each other as mentioned in the comments. i.e.

```
label = label.replace('Branch Library', '').replace('Library', '')
```

However if you have more words you want to remove you could create an actual `shorten_site_name` function that has a set of words to remove:

```
>>> def shorten_site_name(site_name):
...   words_to_remove = {"Branch", "Library"}
...   return ' '.join(w for w in site_name.split() if w not in words_to_remove)
... 
>>> site_names = ["Weston Ranch Branch Library", "Weston Library"]
>>> new_site_names = list(map(lambda site: shorten_site_name(site), site_names))
>>> new_site_names
['Weston Ranch', 'Weston']
```